# Query the hazelcast data having inner object arrays using predicate

Tags: hazelcast, predicate

I have a user Object, Which has inner Object of type Address. Below are the structures of both User and Address.

```
User{
String name;
String id;
String phoneNumber;
List<Address> address
}

Address{
String type;
String streetName;
String houseNumber;
String Country;
int pin
}
```

I am storing the User Objects to the Hazelcast Cache. I would like to query Users whose address type is "Primary" and Country is "US".

The problem I am seeing is that each user can have multiple addresses, How to loop through the address and find the one with type "Primary" and for that particular address type how to query the Country "US". Can we use predicate to achieve this? If so, Please help me with how the predicate can be constructed.

Answer (score 2):

Please check [Querying in Collections and Arrays](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#querying-in-collections-and-arrays) in the Hazelcast documentation.

In your case, you would like to have two conditions on the dependent collection, like:

- `Predicates.equal("address[any].country", "US")`
- `Predicates.equal("address[any].type", "Primary")`

But `any` should apply to the same entity (because you'd like to have `US` as `Primary` country). I don't think you can achieve it with just Predicates.

What you can do, however, is to use [Custom Attributes](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#custom-attributes) and define your own `ValueExtractor` which would cover the logic you need.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution... Could you provide any helping link or code about how using `custom attributes` might solve it? I'd really appreciate any help.